# What does $\Sigma _{XX}$ mean in the context of this equation component, and how can it be resolved?

Tags: matrices, covariance

A paper [I'm reading](http://humancomputation.com/ci2014/papers/Active%20Papers%5CPaper%2037.pdf) contains an equation with the following component:

$ w{}'\Sigma _{XX}w$

I've been told that this element is meant to reflect covariances among individuals.

w stands for weight. There are 428 individuals weighted equally. Therefore, each has a weight of 1/428 (0.0002).

I also have worked out the unique covariance between each pair of individuals. There are n choose k covariances, or 91378 in total. So I have a vector of 91378 covariances.

I am seeking to work out what the element resolves to. How do I use the information I have to work out $ w{}'\Sigma _{XX}w$? Is it just the average covariance?

Comment: It seems $w$ is a vector, which makes $\Sigma_{XX}$ a matrix. Might it be that element $(i,j)$ of the matrix $\Sigma_{XX}$ is the covariance between individual $i$ and individual $j$?

Comment: I do have such a matrix of covariances between individuals, with each individual's variance on the diagonal. Say I call that $\Sigma _{XX}$, how do I then work out the full component $w{}'\Sigma _{XX}w$?

Comment: Let $Y$ be a random variable. Note that the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y) = \operatorname{Var}(Y)$ and that is why the variance of each individual is on the diagonal. The equation $w' \Sigma_{XX} w$ is simply a multiplication of a row vector times a matrix times a column vector. Thus, the result should be a single number. I believe $w = (w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_N) = (\frac{1}{428},\frac{1}{428},\ldots,\frac{1}{428})$.

Comment: I had thought that w' was the column vector, and then when I tried to multiply it by the matrix the answer was undefined. Now that I am doing it your way, it works.